# Reactive Extensions mix multiple sequences

Tags: system.reactive

I'm working in a TCP context and I need to react to incoming data: If too much data is received i need to ignore all but the last received; if no data comes in for a long time I have to send a request to the server.

First proposition is solved like this:

```
 Observable.FromEventPattern<ObjectReceivedEventArgs>( _client, "ObjectReceived" )
           .Throttle( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 500 ) )
           .Subscribe( args => ... );
```

Second proposition is solved with a Timer:

```
Observable.Timer( ... ).Subscribe( ... );
```

Now, I can mix it this two things so I can send a request to the server if no data comes in, in a timely fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make a second subscription to your source event like this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<ObjectReceivedEventArgs>(_client, "ObjectReceived")
          .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
          .StartWith(Unit.Default)
          .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(/*desired timeout here */))
          .Take(1).Repeat()
          .Subscribe(_ => /* poke server here */);
```

What this does is start a stream off with a Unit value and attempt to throttle it with the arrival of events. As long as events arrive within the timeout period, the stream is suppressed by the throttle, as soon as events pause for the timespan then `OnNext` is fired. Note that the `Take(1)` causes the timeout to keep firing after each subsequent pause even if no further events arrive - simply remove that if you want to only call the server one time after events cease.